# Docker: hiding process command names from the host

Tags: docker, process

When running a docker container, is it possible to obfuscate processes' command names from the host? My problem is that one of my processes currently scans the process list to ensure that it's the unique instance, but I'd like to run separate instances in both the container and the host.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the process title inside your code. E.g. on python you can use https://pypi.org/project/setproctitle/, other programming languages should have similar libraries.